# Easy High Side Driver

Tags: transistors

Had a few issues with a high side using darlingtons etc - what would be simplist 
 3v3 logic driven hi side (12V output) driver (I'm thinming fet) that can handle 1-2A for running a solenoid, as a switch - frquncy is VERy low like on for 10 mins, off for 5 etc.
tia

Comment: How about a smart switch / power distribution switch?

Comment: @MattyT2017 If you ask specific questions in your post, you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a P channel MOSFET like this: -

[image]

Taken from my answer to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67775/driving-led-strip-from-microcontroller) Q and A

Comment: Could you reocmmened an SMT fet ideally D PAK that would suffice?

Comment: Product recommendations are generally off-topic. There are plenty of search engines in such places like Farnell, Digikey and Mouser etc..

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

- P channel fet.
- N channel fet with gate driver.
- Relay.
- PNP transistor.
- NPN transistor with base driver.

Or, a you can get a smart high side power switch. Eg: [ITS4142N](https://www.digikey.nl/product-detail/en/infineon-technologies/ITS4142NHUMA1/ITS4142NHUMA1CT-ND/2231154).
Which basically is an N channel fet with booster circuit or even diagnostics and sensing in one package.